# How do I save HTML form field values to localStorage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to get data from an HTML form and store them at localStore, but I'm running into some problems while attempting to tho this.

Let's make a short example:

```
<form class="w3-container" id="form"> 
<p><label>Name</label><input class="w3input" type="text" id="name"></p>
<p><label>Adress</label><input class="w3-input" type="text" id="adress"></p>
<p><label>Number</label><input class="w3-input" type="text" id="number"></p>
<button class="w3-button w3-blue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then JavaScript code:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
localStorage.setItem("adress", document.getElementById("adress").value);
localStorage.setItem("number", document.getElementById("number").value);
```

I have tried a different number of ways to do this but nothing seems to work.
What am I missing?

Comment: Code seems incomplete. If you are storing the data in localStorage, you need to have `onclick` attribute on the Submit button.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to store the data in `localStorage` when Submit button is clicked, your code should be as follows.

```js
function onSubmit() {
  localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
  localStorage.setItem("adress", document.getElementById("adress").value);
  localStorage.setItem("number", document.getElementById("number").value);
}
```

```html
<form class="w3-container" id="form">
  <p><label>Name</label><input class="w3input" type="text" id="name"></p>
  <p><label>Adress</label><input class="w3-input" type="text" id="adress"></p>
  <p><label>Number</label><input class="w3-input" type="text" id="number"></p>
  <button class="w3-button w3-blue" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe you should avoid using inline javascript (unless you're using a framework e.g react).  you should bind the form element to a variable in an external javascript file (or within script tags)  then, listen for the submit event on the form element, then grab and save the values you want.

Comment: Glad for the knowledge share. I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) which was posted as an answer from other user, better explains the difference between usage of `onclick` and `addEventListener`. @Oguntoye

Answer (score 1):

Within `<script></script>` tags or an external js file,

1. Get the form element:
   `const form = document.getElementById('form');`
2. Add a listener to listen for the submit event and save your values:

   ```
   form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
     localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
     localStorage.setItem("adress", document.getElementById("adress").value);
     localStorage.setItem("number", document.getElementById("number").value);
   })
   ```

You should avoid using inline javascript (unless you're using a framework e.g react (then it's not even really inline)).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could add an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)